# How to brick android

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, kernel

I'm currently trying to hard-brick my phone. Yes, you read right. The reason doesn't really matter. I tried flashing wrong recovery/ROM but no success. I could easily recover the smartphone afterwards through SP Flash Tool and MTK Droid. It's about a Gionee P6. I can't flash a kernel because it doesn't allow me, the process of flashing ending with error each time. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about physically? Can you open the device up?

Comment: @AndyYan I don't want to damage the warranty seals XD

Comment: I'm thinking of `dd` zeroes to the kernel partition, effectively zero-filling it. Need root ofc. Not sure if that'll actually work, since normal guys like me don't have the guts to try such risks. If SPFT can't flash a kernel to the phone (as you described) then there should be few if any means of recovery from a missing kernel.

Comment: @AndyYan How can I do that? I'm not very familiar with sending commands from pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily root the phone (or do this in a *working* recovery) then run the following command in a shell:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M count=1
```

Do note that unless you destroy a piece of hardware, a professional engineer can always recover it with special tools.

See this answer of mine: [Using ADB, what command can I use to break/permanently destroy a Galaxy S5?](/a/175974/205764)

Comment: Did the trick, completely unresponsive

Comment: This is the weirdest case I have ever seen but nice to see that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's an MTK device. You can easily hardbrick it using SP Flash tool.
Go to `Format` tab. On `Auto Format Flag` , click on `Format whole flash`. This will format the eMMC memory leaving practically nothing, not even the preloader.
Now click on `Start`. Power off the phone then connect it to the computer. Wait a few seconds. 
Done.

PS: One can still bring it to life using special tools though.

Comment: Can someone detect that this was done purposely? Does it even boot up, like going to boot screen - a blank screen?

Comment: No booting up, no charging, no detecting by a computer. I don't think someone can figure out it was purposely bricked.